# Can't get Django to run simple unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've got a minimal test case in a file called `testDummy.py`, located in `/MyApp/MyApp/` (alongside the default `settings.py`)

```
from django.test import TestCase

class DummyTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("Setup")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Teardown")

    def test_noddy(self):

        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
```

When executing `manage.py test -v 2`, I get ...

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_myapp')...
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table contenttypes_concretemodel
...
Creating table myapp_login_audit
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
test_get_for_concrete_model (django.contrib.contenttypes.tests.ContentTypesTests) ... ok
...
test_shortcut_view (django.contrib.contenttypes.tests.ContentTypesTests) ... ok
test_shortcut_view_with_broken_get_absolute_url (django.contrib.contenttypes.tes
ts.ContentTypesTests) ... ok
test_shortcut_view_without_get_absolute_url (django.contrib.contenttypes.tests.C
ontentTypesTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.389s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_myapp')...
```

However, it always runs the same 10 tests (none of them mine). If I do `manage.py test -v 2 MyApp`, it runs 0 tests.

What am I missing?

(Python3, Django 1.6)

Comment: Have you added `MyApp` to INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS?

Comment: IIRC, unit tests have to be in a file called `tests.py` in the application's root directory to be picked up by `manage.py test`. The file is created automatically when you do `manage.py startapp`.

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/).

Comment: It is included in INSTALLED_APPS - I believe the 2nd command line I showed should've errored if it wasn't.  @Aya Thanks for the links to the docs but I've read them. As per [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/) `Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named “test*.py” under the current working directory.` Which is what I was aiming for. I'll try just `tests.py`

Comment: @Basic Ah. Didn't notice you were using 1.6. I haven't tried 1.6 yet, but it's possible the "under the current working directory" part is misleading. The files may have to be in the application's root directory if it's different from the project's root directory in your case. I often use the same for both, though.

Comment: I was trying to be too clever. I've got quite a complex directory structure and wanted to keep tests close to the code they were testing. Renaming to to `tests.py` seems to have done the trick. If you'd care to post that as an answer, I'll accept in a few days if nobody comes up with a better solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Basic Well, you can probably keep the test scripts where they are. According to the docs it picks up any classes in `tests.py` which are subclasses of `django.test.TestCase`, so you could just do a bunch of imports in `tests.py` along the lines of `from somepackage.testDummy import *`.